# Visual Studio 15.8.0 Preview 2.0 - MVC - Core 2.1 - Adding SOAP as Connected Service - Version for package dotnet-svcutil could not be resolved

Tags: visual-studio, soap, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am working with the following: *Visual Studio 15.8.0 Preview 2.0, ASP.NET Web Application, with Target of .NET Core 2.1.* I am trying to add a SOAP service as a Connected Service. (I had the same problem with VS 15.7.4, so I thought going to the preview version might find this issue fixed)

I chose **Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider**.

When I try to add the SOAP service, I get:

**Version for package `dotnet-svcutil` could not be resolved**

...

*I went the following route without success (mlacouture - mentioned changing nuget.config in directory **svcutil_starter** to fix the location of the svcutil package, then doing dotnet restore on the Nuget package. With this preview version of VS, the location of svcutil in nuget.config is already correct **(C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WCF CONNECTED SERVICE\svcutil\dotnet-svcutil.1.0.0-preview-20406-879.nupkg)**.*

I continue to still get: 
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.300\NuGet.targets(114,5): error : **The local source** 'C:\Users\medwa163\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2018_Jun_22_08_01_15\svcutil_starter\dotnet-svcutil.1.0.0-preview-20406-879.nupkg' **doesn't exist.** [C:\Users\medwa163\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2018_Jun_22_08_01_15\svcutil_starter\svcutil_starter.csproj]. It definitely does exist.

If I copy the package to the same directory at the Nuget.config, and change Nuget.config to point to it, I get the same error. Cleared the nuget cache and same error.

[GitHub Info on Potential Workaround](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2719)

...

Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**I was finally able to find a solution for this.**

I temporarily changed the target of the project from **.NET Core 2.1 to .NET Core 2.0**. Then I was able to add the service.

After that, I changed the target **back to .NET Core 2.1** and tested. I was able to call the service successfully.