# Cannot install dotnet-svcutil with VIsual Studio 2019 to register wsdl services

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, nuget, svcutil.exe

I followed many ways, here the main two:

**Install via Nuget:**
I have created a dedicated .Net Core 2.1 console application.
Adding svutil 2.0.2 via nuget ui i get:

```
Package 'dotnet-svcutil 2.0.2' has a package type 'DotnetTool' that is not supported by project 'TestWS'.   
    
Invalid project-package combination for dotnet-svcutil 2.0.2. DotnetToolReference project style can only contain references of the DotnetTool type  

Package dotnet-svcutil 2.0.2 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package dotnet-svcutil 2.0.2 supports: netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1) / any
```

**Install as global tool**
i run

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-svcutil --version 2.0.2
```

or

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-svcutil
```

but got error, possible causes are corporate proxy authentication and i cannot have proxy url to set it up

final goal is to register a wdsl file. i got it and create manually a .cs class to implement it, but without registering the connected service i'am not able to setup url anche change it for different environment

Comment: `DotnetToolReference` is deprecated already and superseded by `dotnet tool`

Comment: if i open nuget ui, search for svcutil  and install in my project i get that error, don't se how can i use dotnet tool instead of DotnetToolReference: i only make a couple of click on nuget buttons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This package is a tool for dotnet cli rather than for a project. You should install it into dotnet cli.

Check your environment and you have the enough right to control the PC.

Run cmd as **Administrator** and then type:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-svcutil --version 2.0.2
```

[image]

**Or** you should follow [this guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232160/nuget-behind-a-proxy/15463892#15463892) to add your corporate proxy into global `nuget.config` file.

Comment: i don't have admin rights and neither proxy url... IT said me that i have to tell vs to use system proxy without manually setting it

Comment: That sounds bad. To solve the issue, you have to contact your Administrator and give you enough permission to do this. And this is the best way to realize it.

Comment: long job but now is done. svutil correctly installed but now when i try to add connected service i still have the error: Version for package `dotnet-svcutil-lib` could not be resolved. i found that post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50972501/visual-studio-15-8-0-preview-2-0-mvc-core-2-1-adding-soap-as-connected-ser. but net core 2.0 or 2.1 or others makes no differences